# SonarQube 6.7.1 WEB not work with JDBC 42.1.4 [default]

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

OS: Uduntu 16.04 64-bit LTS
SonarQube: 6.7.1
PostgreSql: 9.5
Java: 1.8.0_144

Default SonarQube has JDBC 42.1.4 and the following error in web.log:

```
ERROR web[][o.postgresql.Driver] Connection error:
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:275)
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:194)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:450)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:252)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
        at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.addObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1617)
        at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.ensureMinIdle(GenericObjectPool.java:1575)
        at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.access$700(GenericObjectPool.java:190)
        at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool$Evictor.run(GenericObjectPool.java:1709)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: localhost
```

but when i update to JDBC 4.2 Driver, 42.2.1 work well.

Maybe someone from sonarqube see and fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed the version of PostgreSQL driver packaged in SonarQube 6.7.1 has some bugs. Driver is upgraded in SonarQube 6.7.2, not released at the time of writing.
See a related ticket: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-10296